# Counting days excluding weekends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a library-style system in Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate the overdue days while excluding weekends when a borrowed item is returned.  Right now I'm just calculating "dayslate" as the difference between the due date and the date the item was actually returned, but I want to exclude weekends, since items can only be returned on weekdays.

This is my first real experience with Ruby and Rails, so my apologies if I'm missing something obvious.  Thanks for any help you all can provide.

Here's the code I have for the "return" function:

```
   def return
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
     today = Date.today
     dayslate = today - @product.due_date
     if @product.due_date >= today
       @product.borrower = @product.check_out = @product.due_date = @product.extended_checkout = nil
       @product.save!
       flash[:notice] = "Okay, it's checked in!"
       redirect_to(products_url)
     else
       @product.borrower = @product.check_out = @product.due_date = @product.extended_checkout = nil
       @product.save!
       flash[:notice] = "Checked in, but it was #{dayslate} days late!"
       redirect_to(products_url)
     end
 end
```

Comment: return is a ruby keyword. You should probably find a better name for your method.

Comment: Good point, that hadn't even occurred to me.  I'll change it to something more specific.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a snippet of code to find the number of weekdays in a Range of Date objects

```
require 'date'
# Calculate the number of weekdays since 14 days ago
p ( (Date.today - 14)..(Date.today) ).select {|d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size
```

This is how I would use it in your case.

```
class Product
  def days_late
    weekdays_in_date_range( self.due_date..(Date.today) )
  end

  protected
  def weekdays_in_date_range(range)
    # You could modify the select block to also check for holidays
    range.select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That first snippet is beautifully written. Can't think of it being more eloquent.

Answer (score 3):

```
sunday, saturday = 0, 6
weekend = [sunday, saturday]
((start_date..end_date).collect(&:wday) - weekend).count
```

Answer (score 2):

If holidays matter to you (i.e. you don't want to count a day as a weekday if it is a holiday), you might want to look into http://rubyforge.org/projects/holidays/.  If you combine the loop that @md5sum mentioned with a check to see if the weekday is a holiday, you may be golden.

Answer (score 2):

Um.. just one more thing which could be useful since it's your first rails experience - pay attention to that business logic in the controller. Your model, that's where it belongs.

Comment: Could you clarify?  I don't have a background in programming, but I've been working my way through the Pragmatic Programmers Ruby and Rails books, and I'm trying to stay consistent with their examples.

Comment: Ideally, all that your controller should be doing is pull some models from db, call some methods on them, optionally put something into the flash and then render or redirect. These are responsibilities of a controller in our classical MVC. In your case, those date calculations and @product attributes assignments are really a part of the Product model, because it's business logic.

Comment: This is better served as a comment than an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [this](http://everydayblog.net/2009/03/09/add-weekdays-in-ruby-on-rails/) page and see if you can add a counter into the loop and check against the current date through each iteration.

Comment: I was just looking at this, and does look like a step in the right direction.  No mention is made of holidays, though.  I don't know if the OP cares about holidays, but he might, especially if this app will be calculating a late fee based on the number of days the item was returned late.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @Marini's post it is possible to eliminate the overhead of generating a range of dates:

```
def weekdays(date1, date2)
  wday = date1.wday
  (0..(date2-date1)).count {|offset| ((wday + offset) % 7 % 6) > 0}
end
```

`% 7` turns each offset into a weekday, and `% 6` returns `0` for Saturday (6) or Sunday (0)

Answer (score 1):

calculate week days of the current_month

```
start_date = Date.today.beginning_of_month
end_date = Date.today.end_of_month

(start_date..end_date).select{|a| a.wday < 6 && a.wday > 0}.count
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simpler and more readable than the accepted answer:

```
require 'date'
to = Date.parse('2017-02-02')
from = to - 14
(from..to).count { |d| !d.sunday? && !d.saturday? }
#=> 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a faster way to counting weekend days, you can get days count excluding weekends by `(start_date..end_date).size - weekend_count`:

```
def weekend_count(start_date, end_date)
  size = (end_date - start_date).to_i
  count = 0
  if start_date.wday != 0
    size -= (7 - start_date.wday).to_i
    count += 1
  end

  left_over  = size % 7
  if left_over == 0
    count = (count / 7) * 2
  else
    size -=  left_over
    count += (size / 7) * 2 + 1
  end
  count
end
```

Compare with `[0, 6].include? date.wday`, see my [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/fffx/2f6fd2d6a8c48362c3dfab99afc5a441) result:

```
Distance 10
Optimized result:  4
Normal result:     4
                                                  user     system      total        real
Optimized                                     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000018)
Normal                                        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000032)
Distance 100
Optimized result:  29
Normal result:     29
                                                  user     system      total        real
Optimized                                     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000006)
Normal                                        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000094)
Distance 1000
Optimized result:  286
Normal result:     286
                                                  user     system      total        real
Optimized                                     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
Normal                                        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000650)
Distance 10000
Optimized result:  2858
Normal result:     2858
                                                  user     system      total        real
Optimized                                     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
Normal                                        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004995)
Distance 100000
Optimized result:  28572
Normal result:     28572
                                                  user     system      total        real
Optimized                                     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
Normal                                        0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.064223)
```

Answer (score 0):

neutrino is quite right about moving all the logic that isnt involved in the display/render/redirect to the models.

E.g.

```
class ProductLoan
  def due_date_passed?
    days_late > 0
  end

  def days_late
    Date.today - due_date
  end

  def complete!
    self.borrower = self.check_out = self.due_date = self.extended_checkout = nil
    save
  end
end

class ReturnsController
  def create
    @product = ProductLoan.find(params[:id])

    if @product.due_date_passed?
      flash[:notice] = "Okay, it's checked in!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Checked in, but it was #{@product.days_late} days late!"
    end
    @product.complete!

    redirect_to products_url
  end
end
```

Ive just typed this without testing it but, something along these lines could calculate the days passed excluding weekends:

```
class DateOffsetCalculator
  DAYS_IN_A_WEEK = 7
  DAYS_IN_A_WEEKEND = 2

  def initialize(date)
    @date = date
  end

  def compute
    days_passed - weekend_days_passed
  end

  def days_passed
    (Date.today - @date).to_i
  end

  def weekend_days_passed
    weekends_passed * DAYS_IN_A_WEEKEND
  end

  def weekends_passed
    rounded_up_week_days / DAYS_IN_A_WEEK
  end

  def rounded_up_week_days
    days_passed + commercial_working_day_correction
  end

  def commercial_working_day_correction
    @date.cwday - 1
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for dates that occur in the middle of the week.

Answer (score 0):

The top solution is fine and I know I shouldn't worry about performance, but there's a part of me that's bothered about counting the number of weekdays by generating a collection and iterating over it because the time to calculate is a linear function of the difference between the two dates.

The answer can be mathematically calculated in fixed time if you think it through.  You can think about it in two parts:

**PART 1 - NUMBER OF WEEKS BETWEEN**

If the days difference is greater than a week, you can count each 7 day week as having 5 weekdays and "remove" the full weeks from consideration.

**PART 2 - DAYS IN THE PARTIAL WEEK**

Having subtracted the full weeks you can look at the simplified problem of how many weekdays lie between two days on a 7 day span.  If you build a table you'll see there's a pretty simple rule or you can repeat the logic used in the winning solution but only over a interval of at most 7 days.