# Excluding weekends from a date range,

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app is intended to calculate sick/vacation days. The commented out part is what I was using to track how long a vacation was, but it doesn't exclude weekends. I read this answer ([Counting days excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001765/counting-days-excluding-weekends)) and really tried to adopt it to my model but right now my duration equation is coming back "0" regardless of the data I put in it.

```
class Furlough < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :duration, :note, :date_from, :date_to, :description, :employee_id
  belongs_to :employee
  validates_presence_of :date_from, :date_to, :employee_id, :description

  # def duration
  #     (date_to - date_from).to_i 
  # end

  def duration
    only_weekdays(date_to..(date_from))
  end

  protected
  def only_weekdays(range)
    range.select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size
  end


end
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `duration` to:

```
only_weekdays(date_from..date_to)
```

Comment: Bless you. Did the other answer have that syntax "weekdays_in_date_range( self.due_date..(Date.today) )" because Date.today wasn't a fixed variable like it kind of is in my model?

Comment: No.  Feel free to add as many unnecessary pairs of parenthesis you want.  :-)